# Make sure the prerequisite module are installed on the unix/linux os

Tags: perl, module, cpan

I am cpan module which have prerequisite on other module. Is there any process to make sure the module can be installed only after the installation of the prerequisite module while
manual installation of the module.

```
     perl MakeFile.pl
     make
     make test
     make install
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use a standard build management module like 
[`ExtUtils::MakeMaker`](http://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker) or [`Module::Build`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Module%3a%3aBuild), which have conventions to handle prerequisites.

For `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`, the convention is to pass prerequisite information in the `PREREQ_PM` argument to the `WriteMakefile` function. Here's what it might look like:

```
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

WriteMakefile(
    NAME => 'My::Module',
    AUTHOR => 'Me',
    VERSION_FROM => 'lib/My/Module.pm',

    PREREQ_PM => {

        'Some::Module' => 0.42,       # need >=v0.42 of Some::Module
        'Some::Other::Module' => 0,   # but any version of Some::Other::Module is ok

    }
    dist => ... ,
    clean => ... ,
    ...
);
```